# Return a list of classes created dynamically that are named the same as the names passed in in Python

Tags: python, class, dynamically-generated

I want to write a function where it returns a list of dynamically created classes for a given list of names passed in,Each class should have a method in it called is_the_one().. which takes in  a string.

```
def get_dynamic_classes(self,classes):
  def is_the_one(self,s): return inspect.isclass(s)
  classnames = []
  for i in range(len(classes)):
    NewClass = type(list[i], (object, ), {})
    setattr(NewClass, 'is_the_one', is_the_one)
     classnames.append(NewClass)
  return classnames
```

I tried the above but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does your example confuse `classes` and `classnames`, one representing the contents of the other?

Comment: No.it is just a variable.

Comment: No, they are definitely *two* variables, and each carries the name matching the meaning of the other.  `get_dynamic_classes()` should have a parameter names `classnames` and the growing array in it should be named `classes`.  But nevermind …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def is_the_one(self, s):
        return inspect.isclass(s)

def get_dynamic_classes(classes):
    return [type(i, (BaseClass, ), {}) for i in classes]
```